# I am testing a variable and I keep getting android.widget.EditText@

Tags: java, android, variables, button, android-edittext

Normally when I have a problem, I just google it but I am having a hard time finding a solution for this so I hope somebody can help me out here.

I have a simple activity that has one edittext, one textview, and a button. The idea is that input from the textview goes into String empid and then I will display it just to test that it is working (which it is not)

```
package com.Jonathon.mces.employeeportal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Set extends Activity {
    private static final String EMPID = "0";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    final EditText tv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.empidtxt);

    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            submit(tv);

        }
    });

}

  public void submit(EditText tv) {
     String empid = tv.toString(); 
     TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
     test.setText(empid);
}


}
```

Comment: the thing is you need to use tv.getText().toString().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably wanting to use `tv.getText().toString();`, the toString() method on the `EditText` `Object` won't be what you want.

Comment: Everybody who replied gave the same answer so I thank all of you. But because yours was the one on top I just went ahead and marked yours as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
EditText tv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.empidtxt);
String empid =tv.getText().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
    public void submit(EditText tv) {
       String empid = tv.toString(); 
       TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
       test.setText(empid);
    }
```

to this:

```
    public void submit(EditText tv) {
         String empid = tv.getText().toString(); 
         TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
         test.setText(empid);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get text from EditText:

```
EditText tv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.empidtxt);
String empid = tv .getText().toString();
```